# Error evaluating a derivative on Python (with .subs, .evalf and .lambdify)

Tags: python, evaluate, lambdify, evalf

I am trying to separately compute the elements of a Taylor expansion and did not obtain the results I was supposed to. The function to approximate is x**321, and the first three elements of that Taylor expansion around x=1 should be:
1 + 321(x-1) + 51360(x-1)**2
For some reason, the code associated with the second term is not working.
See my code below.

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sy.Symbol('x')
f = x**321
x0 = 1
func0 = f.diff(x,0).subs(x,x0)*((x-x0)**0/factorial(0))
print(func0)
func1 = f.diff(x,1).subs(x,x0)*((x-x0)**1/factorial(1))
print(func1)
func2 = f.diff(x,2).subs(x,x0)*((x-x0)**2/factorial(2))
print(func2)
```

The prints I obtain running this code are

```
1
321x - 321
51360*(x - 1)**2
```

I also used .evalf and .lambdify but the results were the same. I can't understand where the error is coming from.

```
f = x**321
x = sy.Symbol('x')

def fprime(x):
    return sy.diff(f,x)

DerivativeOfF = sy.lambdify((x),fprime(x),"numpy")
print(DerivativeOfF(1)*((x-x0)**1/factorial(1)))
321*x - 321
```

I'm obviously just starting with the language, so thank you for your help.

Comment: What package is behind your sy ? Could your include your imports in the beginning of your code?

Comment: Where is the error? From your output everything seems to work. You already printed the correct output

Comment: no I think she means in the second row there should be  321*(x-1)

Comment: But that's just a printing issue with the output, not an error. Both forms are equivalent

Comment: Tell her that not me. Oh wait you just did :P

Comment: I appologise,@Sharku the imports are
    import sympy as sy
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@Bazingaa I don't see how it could be a print error, if you could just explain please.

Comment: What I was saying is that `321x - 321` or `321(x - 1)` are the same thing. But your headline says 'Error evaluating...'. So I just said that you can't call it an error. It's just a matter of SciPy output representation I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a beginners guide how to Taylor expand in python. Check it out perhaps all your questions are answered there:

http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2015/03/taylor-series-with-python-and-sympy.html

I tested your code and it works fine. like Bazingaa pointed out in the comments it is just an issue how python saves functions internally. One could argument that for a computer it takes less RAM to save `321*x - 321` instead of `321*(x - 1)**1`.
In your first output line it also gives you `1` instead of `(x - 1)**0`

Comment: My code actually started from a very similar loop, and following these instructions but exclusively changing the function I obtain the described mistake.

Comment: I just realised what @Bazingaa and you were saying. So obvious, very embarrassed right now.